# Add a list of Maps in Firebase from Flutter Web

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I have a Map<String, dynamic> class and I need to add in the "categories" field a list of Map<String, dynamic> with values I get from a class.

```
final Map<String, dynamic> data = await partnerModifyData.toMap();

final List<int> listCategoriesIds =
    partnerModifyData.companyCategoriesPtrSelected.cast<int>().toList();

final List<CategoryData> categoriesData =
    listCategoyData.where((category) => listCategoriesIds.contains(category.id)).toList();

final categoriesFormatted = categoriesData
    .map(
      (category) => {
        'categories': {
          'id': category.id,
          'title': category.title,
        }
      },
    )
    .toList();

for (final category in categoriesFormatted) {
  data.addEntries(category.entries);
}
```

However, when using data.addEntries(category.entries), it overwrites the old data/map with the new one. I need it to be added to the old value, so that it stays in this format:
[Firebase Example Map List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvcEv.png)

Comment: You need to show your code definition of `addEntries`... Is it possible that you are using `set` instead of `add`. Or the other possibility is you are addingto the exact same document which forces the overwrite. More info here [link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)

Comment: Can you try printing  the the data in `categoriesFormatted` list and add it in the question? Also, instead of `addEntries` , try using `addAll` as mentioned [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/Map/addAll.html).